# How do I view file path of markup through browser

Tags: html, path, firebug, markup

I was wondering if there is any way in which the file path of a piece of HTML markup, can be identified through a browser development tool like Firebug?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "file path" exactly, can you clarify? Usually with Firebug you inspect one document whose path is known

Comment: What I am getting at is: looking at a page's generated code in say Firebug, clicking on a segment of that code and being able to trace the file from where it came, through a file path on the domain. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't understand the "from where it came" bit. You mean HTML generated through an AJAX request?

Comment: @Pekka웃 from how I understand Glynn question, the intent is to find out where a specific piece of HTML code was generated, i.e. whether it comes from the server (and from which server-side script) or whether some JavaScript created it. Glynn, please edit your question to clarify what exactly you want to know and provide information on what you've tried so far and some examples.

Comment: @Sebastian yeah, that sounds like the most likely explanation! As far as I know, that is not possible, at least not with any debugging tool I'm aware of. Glynn, if that's what you want to know, you (someone else) should make an edit to the question to make it clearer

Comment: My question is clear! It's a very simple, straightforward question! Never mind!!